# Underscore Templates: passing variables from a parent template to a child template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette, underscore.js-templating

I have an underscore template that looks roughly like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="list-template">
    <%= listHeaderTemplate(); %>
    stuff that
    displays a list
    <%= listFooterTemplate(); %>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="list-footer-template">
    <%= foo %>
</script>

<script>
listTemplate = _.template($("#list-template").html());
listHeaderTemplate = _.template($("#list-header-template").html());
listFooterTemplate = _.template($("#list-footer-template").html());
</script>
```

What I want to do is to pass the full set of variables that are passed to listTemplate() into listFooterTemplate(). For example,

```
listTemplate({foo: "foo"});
```

I can do this by modifying the calls to listHeaderTemplate() / listFooterTemplate() in list-template to package the locals into a dictionary (i.e. listFooterTemplate({foo: foo});) but that seems rather onerous, particularly when a large set of variables are in use, and it requires me to know inside of list-template which variables list-footer-template might use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile an Underscore template, Underscore turns your template inside out and builds a function that looks, more or less, like this:

```
function(obj) {
    // Some set up...
    with(obj || {}) {
        // The template as JavaScript...
    }
    return theTemplateText;
}
```

You can't depend on the parameter being called `obj`, that's bound to break soon or later. You should have safe access to the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object though. Having `arguments` allows you to call other functions with exactly the same arguments as the current function without having to know what the arguments are, you just use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

If you have `listHeaderTemplate` and `listFooterTemplate` available to your template, you can simply say:

```
<script type="text/template" id="list-template">
    <%= listHeaderTemplate.apply(this, arguments) %>
    stuff that
    displays a list
    <%= listFooterTemplate.apply(this, arguments) %>
</script>
```

An easy way is to pass those functions as arguments to your template:

```
var listTemplate       = _.template($("#list-template").html());
var listHeaderTemplate = _.template($("#list-header-template").html());
var listFooterTemplate = _.template($("#list-footer-template").html());

var html = listTemplate({
    foo: 11,
    listHeaderTemplate: listHeaderTemplate,
    listFooterTemplate: listFooterTemplate
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vwjm1kta/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one could pass the data object via JSON.stringify and a HTML data-* attribute.

```
<script type="text/template" id="list-template">
<div id="my-list-template" data-us-tmpl-data="<%= JSON.stringify(data) %>">
</div>
</script>
```